# why i am facing this error: request for member 'size' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int [n]' for(int j=arr.size()-1; j>=0; j--){

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, reverse, stdvector

I am facing an error:

> request for member size in arr which is of non class type

I could not figure out what is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
// reversing an array;`

int main(){
    int n, a;
    std::vector<int> vect;
    cout << "enter size: ";
    cin >> n;

    int arr[n];
    cout << "enter numbers in array ---> " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    //logic to reverse

    for(int j=arr.size()-1; j>=0; j--){
        a = arr[j];
        vect.push_back(a);
    }

    for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
        cout << vect[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `arr` is not a `std::vector`

Comment: `arr` is a C-style array. It doesn't have any member functions. Further, `int arr[n];` is not standard C++. The size of an array is required to be a compile-time constant. Your compiler is doing you a disservice by allowing it. But the size of the array is `n`.

Comment: See [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097).

Comment: first time today - use std::vector

Answer (score 0):

I don't think array type has the function size
you can probably use vector instead of arr(  vector arr(n,0)  )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The built in array does not have a .size() member function. If you wanted that you would need to use the array in the array header file. But instead you could use `for(int j=n-1; j>=0; j--){`.

This is your solution:

```cpp
    #include<iostream>
    #include <vector>
    
    
    using namespace std;
    // reversing an array;`
    
    int main(){
        int n, a;
        std::vector<int> vect;
        cout << "enter size: ";
        cin >> n;
    
        int arr[n];
        cout << "enter numbers in array ---> " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
    
       //logic to reverse
    
        for(int j=n-1; j>=0; j--){
            a = arr[j];
            vect.push_back(a);
        }
    
        for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
            cout << vect[k];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature. And a variable length array is declared in your code:

```
cout << "enter size: ";
cin >> n;

int arr[n];
```

Secondly, arrays are not classes. They do not have member functions. So the expression `arr.size()` is incorrect.

If the compiler supports the function `std::size()` declared in the header `<iterator>` for variable length arrays, you could use the expression `std::size(arr)` instead of `arr.size()`.

Though, instead of the `for` loop, you could just write:

```
#include <iterator>

//...

vect.assign( std::rbegin( arr ), std::rend( arr ) );
```